# How to change themes in custom keyboard in android

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

@Override public View onCreateInputView() {

```
    //Start SharedPreferences Fetch
    SharedPreferences pref1=getSharedPreferences("test",1);
    int theme=pref1.getInt("theme1",1);

    int theme_1=pref1.getInt("theme2",2);

    if(theme==1)
    {
        this.mInputView= (LatinKeyboardView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input2,null);
    }
     else if(theme_1==1)
    {
        this.mInputView= (LatinKeyboardView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input,null);
    }
    //End SharedPreferences Fetch
```

//       mInputView = (LatinKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
 //               R.layout.input, null);

```
    this.mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
//    mInputView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
   this.mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    return this.mInputView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) might be what you are looking for. Instead of inflating based on the current context, you can create a ContextThemeWrapper, and use that to inflate your XML.

```
Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(context,themeId);
LayoutInflator.from(themedContext).inflate(...)
```